# How to add page refresh in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular-material

I tried the following code. I want to add page auto-refresh when clicking game route. Because when I moved to the game page data did not auto-refresh until page reload

```
  <mat-list-item routerLink="{{routes.Gamecard}}" routerLinkActive="active">
    <mat-icon>games</mat-icon> GAMES
  </mat-list-item>
```

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem i know two ways:

1. Try to use `[href]="routes.Gamecard"` instead `routerLink="{{routes.Gamecard}}"` `routerLinkActive="active"`, this is the crutch, but, i think this can work.
2. Create the refresh method in your game-page class, and try to set data in this method by click on your list item, if you are already on the game page.

Are you using `ngOnInit` interface? Maybe this is what you need

Comment: Yeh I'm using ngOnlnit

Comment: @LochanaT, if previously variant does not resolve your problem, i can to propache like solution this - add   this code to yor angular component:
HTML:
 `<mat-list-item (click)="refresh()">
    <mat-icon>games</mat-icon> GAMES
  </mat-list-item>`
TS:

`refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
}`

Comment: @LochanaT, Or, like variant, you can add `refresh()` function from previously commentary into `onInit()` method in your gamePageComponent.ts, if I right understand your problem, this can be right solution